# VBA Excel ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect not removing the known password?

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason `.Unprotect` is not removing the password.
I can set a password just fine with a macro I made but when I attempt to remove the same exact password with the below code for some reason `ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=pw_check` does not work. `ActiveWorkbook.HasPassword` appears to be returning `True` when it should be returning `False`. For the life of me I cannot find any post explaining this behavior so I must conclude I am using `.Unprotect` incorrectly.

```
Sub RemovePassword()
    Dim pw_check As Variant
    Dim fname As String
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    fname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ' Verify with user before continuing '
    If MsgBox("You are about to remove password encryption from this file and save. Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    pw_check = "KNOWN_PASSWORD"

retry_pass:

    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=pw_check
    Debug.Print (ActiveWorkbook.HasPassword)

    If ActiveWorkbook.HasPassword = False Then
        ' prep file dialog window '
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        ' With file dialog set title, clear filters if any, and validate if show was valid and can save or not. '
        With fd
            .Title = "Please select where to save the encrypted file."
            .Filters.Clear

            If .Show = True Then
                On Error GoTo exit_sub
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Name
                MsgBox "File: " & fname & " saved!"
            Else
                MsgBox "Cancelled"
            End If
        End With

    Else
        pw_check = Application.InputBox("Invalid password please provide another password and try again.")
        If pw_check = False Then
            MsgBox ("Process cancelled.")
            GoTo exit_sub
        ElseIf pw_check = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox ("Nothing was entered.")
            GoTo retry_pass
        Else
            GoTo retry_pass
        End If
    End If

exit_sub:

End Sub
```

Comment: You can reprotect with no password then "re-unprotect".

Comment: @TimWilliams Hum. That seams like a band-aid where one should not need to exist. Is that the only option? Does my code appear it should work? Is this a bug or a mistake in my code is really what I am after.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have tried to `ActiveWorkbook.Protect ""` and then `ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=""` But `Debug.Print (ActiveWorkbook.HasPassword)` still returns `True`. So that did not fix the problem here. Am I using `Debug.Print (ActiveWorkbook.HasPassword)` Incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `ActiveWorkbook.HasPassword` reflects the password you apply when using the relvant arguments in the `SaveAs` method (or manually via the SaveAs dialog) and not the password applied using the `Protect` method.

```
Sub Tester()

    Debug.Print "1", ThisWorkbook.HasPassword   '>> False

    ThisWorkbook.Protect "blah"

    ThisWorkbook.Save

    Debug.Print "2", ThisWorkbook.HasPassword   '>> False

    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect "blah"

    Debug.Print "3", ThisWorkbook.HasPassword   '>> False

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.FullName, Password:="blah"

    Debug.Print "4", ThisWorkbook.HasPassword   '>> *True*

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.FullName, Password:=""

    Debug.Print "5", ThisWorkbook.HasPassword   '>> False

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting. That shows that `Unprotect` is not working the way the documentation implies. I guess I will have to rewrite my code to just save as `""`. I will work on this tomorrow when I get back in the office. This will probably be the solution I end up using but that still does not explain the failure of `Unprotect`.

Comment: `Unprotect` is for removing the protection added when you use `Workbook/Worksheet.Protect`.  It's not for the "saveas" password.

Comment: So if I protected the worksheet with `Workbook.Protect` and then just do a normal save as without the password that should suffice? Hum. Now I am curious what method the File > Info > Protect Workbook is using.